# FormView with get method doesn't show the form

Tags: django, formview

Thanks for read :/

When I remove the "get" from the view, the form works, but when I put it back, it doesn't render.

URL at the browser:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/activate?tpr=1140277&idpr=42

URLs:

```
url(r'^activate', Activation_vw.as_view(), name='activate')
```

VIEW:

```
class Activation_vw(FormView):
    template_name = 'activate.html'
    form_class = Activation_Form
    success_url = '/dashboard/'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        tokenProspect_v = request.GET.get('tpr')
        idProspect_v = request.GET.get('idpr')

        USER = USERS.objects.filter(
            id=idProspect_v).values('id', 'email', 'token')

        if int(tokenProspect_v) != int(USER[0]['token']):
            message = "Check the URL"
        else:
            message = USER[0]['email']

        context = {'msg': message}
        return self.render_to_response(context)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # No code yet
        return super(Activation, self).form_valid(form)
```

FORM:

```
class Activation_Form(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
```

TEMPLATE:

```
Hello, {{ msg }}
<form action="" method="POST"> 
    {%csrf_token%}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Activate</button>
</form>
```

All of them have the imports at the top of each file.

The `get` function works perfectly, I receive the `tpr` and the `idpr` but the `form` doesn't and because of that the form `form_valid` and the `success_url` doesn't work neither.

I suspect something is wrong in the return of my `get`, but can't figured out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because your `form` is not being passed in the context:

```
context = {'msg': message}
return self.render_to_response(context)
```

You can use `get_context_data` to get the context and update it as you go:

```
context = self.get_context_data(msg=message)
return self.render_to_response(context)
```

This will call the `get_context_data` from the super class and include the `form` to the context along with adding the `message`.